# SVG not getting displayed in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, rendering, blogger

I have used a couple of svg images from [OpenClipart](http://openclipart.org/people/shokunin/runer_start.svg) in my [site](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/). The **svg** images get properly displayed in Chrome and Firefox. But, when I see the site is IE11 the image is shown as below. I tried a couple of tips from SO and other sites, but they didn't make any difference.

[image]

[Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/) is the site built using blogger. And here is the corresponding html code.

```
<a href="http://www.thecloudavenue.com/search/label/gettingstarted">
   <img src="http://openclipart.org/people/shokunin/runer_start.svg" style="border: none" height="110" width="110" align="middle"/>
</a>
```

How to get around this? If I replace svg with some other type, then it should work. But, I am curious why svg are getting displayed.

Answer (score 2):

IE support for SVG deviates from the standard in several areas. Here are a few:

- Properties of a marker element inherit at the point of reference, not from the ancestors of the `marker` element
- The `pathLength` attribute is not supported
- Parameters for `viewBox` elements in fragment specifications may be delimited by single spaces in addition to commas
- The `display` property affects `pattern` elements and references to those `pattern` elements.
- SMIL animation is not supported. In addition, no references to `animation` elements, properties, attributes, interfaces, or data types in other chapters of [SVG 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) are supported.
- For data types that can be animated, the default setting for the `animVal` attribute is `animVal = baseVal`.

**References**

- [MS-SVG:2.1 Normative Variations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934774)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following declaring the svg containers with the image tags inside. This example has two images so I can toggle an active/inactive condition with Javascript. Also you must close the image tags manually, "<image />" self closing tags are not allowed in IE.

```
<svg id="globalNav_icon_usersSearch" height="20" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <image class="icon_search" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20"  xlink:href="svg/icon_search.svg"></image>
        <image class="icon_search_grey" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20"  xlink:href="svg/icon_seacrh_grey2.svg"></image>
      </svg>
```

Comment: In addition you could use a location.href Javascript call to perform the anchor function.